# Use ENV variables in Angular proxy configuration

Tags: angular, typescript, proxy

I successfully implemented a proxy for my Angular CLI application. The proxy works well. The proxy configuration is in a proxy.conf.js file, and looks like this:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
    "/api/assets/*",
    ],
    target: "http://localhost:4200/assets/",
    pathRewrite: {
    "/api": ""
    },
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Again, it is functional, and requests like `/api/assets/data.json` get redirected to `http://localhost:4200/assets/data.json`

What I try to achieve is to use a variable defined in my `environment.ts` instead of hardcoding the `http://localhost:4200` URL.

However, I can't get it working. When trying to import a variable in the `environment.ts`file with the standard import command

```
import {environment} from "./src/environments/environment";
```

I get the following error :

```
Unexpected token {
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
import {environment} from "./src/environments/environment";
```

---

Therefore my question : How to correctly import a variable from `environment.ts` into my `proxy.conf.js file` ?

Using :

- Angular core v7.3.6
- Angular CLI v7.3.6
- Typescript v3.2.4

Comment: Why do you need to do that? `--proxyConfig` is only available with `ng serve` which you use for your local machine. So, using `environment` file does not make sense for this config.

Comment: Indeed, for this specific example it wouldn't make much sense. But I'd like to retrieve automatically the port number (4200 by default) that would be stored as a variable in `environment.ts`, so a variable access is needed anyway.

Comment: You may need something from `environment` file during build processes but I still think you won't need to read anything from `environment` for the `proxy.conf.js`. You can simply write anything you want, it is for your local machine